# Saleforce OEM Services and Platform Solution Reseller Agreement

Tags: oem

I am looking at investing in a company that has a Salesforce OEM Services and Platform Solution Reseller Agreement..

Is this simply an ISV or OEM agreement or something different and how hard is it to obtain?

Answer (score 1):

OEM and ISV agreements have several differences:

- ISVforce partners typically sell apps that depend on Sales Cloud or Service Cloud and that augment those clouds' functions. ISVforce partners sell only to existing Salesforce customers.
- OEM partners sell a full application that has no dependency on Sales Cloud or Service Cloud, and they sell to both existing and new Salesforce customers. Existing customers install OEM embedded apps just as they would ISVforce apps. For new customers, you deliver an org with your app installed.
- If you are an ISVforce partner, order submission is the spark that sets billing and revenue sharing in motion. If you are an OEM partner, order submission also sets provisioning in motion. OEM partners selling to new customers must provision an Embedded Edition license to all your app’s users. Licenses dictate who can use your product and for how long. The embedded license gives your customers access to the Salesforce platform your app is built on.

Either way, there are several steps involved, the first of which is to join the [partner program](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Partner_Program). There is an [education center](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Partner_Community_User) which goes into detail about the different processes and policies.

**References**

- [Learn About Licenses Unit | Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/appexchange_licensing/appexchange_licensing_sell)
- [Channel Order App Basics | Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/channel-order-app-basics/)
- [Partner_Business_Org](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/general/Partner_Business_Org)
- [Enable Salesforce Platform license to schedule reports - Ideas - Salesforce Trailblazer Community](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000JcxJAAS)
- [Expose API / Objects for assigning Managed Package Licenses to Users - Ideas - Salesforce Trailblazer Community](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kvq4AAA)
- [Cloud Reseller Policies (pdf)](https://c1.sfdcstatic.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/legal/Agreements/alliance-agreements-and-terms/cloudresellerpolicies.pdf)
- [OEM User License Comparison (pdf)](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/oem_user_license_comparison_tipsheet.pdf)
- [Agreements - Salesforce.com](https://www.salesforce.com/company/legal/agreements/)